# Oracle SQL how to check if a field has a certain value/values

Tags: sql, oracle, forms, plsql, oracle11g

I have a query that I am trying to write, I need to find the data that has special characters in it.

I know how to use like '%example%', but I want to search for multiple special characters rather than a few (which I can use OR), so I made a new table that contains all the special characters that I am looking for.

ex:
select * from table1
where field1 like '%*%'
OR field1 like '%$%'
.
.
.
So here is my question: Can I use the table I have created in the above query to avoid writing many lines of code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option.

Sample table:

```
SQL> select ename, job from emp order by job, ename;

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
FORD       ANALYST
SCOTT      ANALYST
ADAMS      CLERK
JAMES      CLERK
MILLER     CLERK
SMITH      CLERK
BLAKE      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
ALLEN      SALESMAN
MARTIN     SALESMAN
TURNER     SALESMAN
WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

This is your "new" table, containing strings you'd want to search for within a column in sample table above:

```
SQL> select * from test;

WORD
----
GER
LER
```

This is the query - searching for employees whose job contains "words" stored in the `test` table:

```
SQL> select e.ename, e.job
  2  from emp e join test t on instr(e.job, t.word) > 0;

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
JONES      MANAGER
BLAKE      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
SMITH      CLERK
ADAMS      CLERK
JAMES      CLERK
MILLER     CLERK

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `INNER JOIN` as follows :

```
SELECT t.name
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN regTable r on t.name like '%' || r.reg || '%';
```

Or you can simply use `regexp_like` as follows :

```
select *
from mytable
where regexp_like(name, '[*$]');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QbgGzoU-)

Comment: `distinct` and `join` are superfluous as long as SQL has `exists` predicate: `...where exists(select null from criteria cr where t.colname like '%' || cr.value || '%')`

Comment: Correct, thank you astentx